# Реклама в браузерах

Tags: windows, браузер

Помогите избавиться от рекламы. Появляются небольшие прямоугольные окна с рекламой сверху, или снизу, или по бокам экрана. В любом браузере, на любой вкладке. Ужасно достала, особенно при просмотре фильмов. ((

Comment: У меня какой-то chrome extension так баловался. Кроме шуток.

Comment: 100% вирус. Необходимо лечение.

Answer (score 2):

1. Видна ли та же реклама при просмотре с другого компьютера? Если нет, проверьтесь на вирусы и malware. Вы не ставили никаких «левых» программ? Или может быть случайно забыли снять птичку «поставить эту фигню тоже» при инсталляции?
2. Если проблема не в вирусах/malware, просто поставьте [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/ru/) и забудьте о рекламе навсегда. Ну, почти навсегда.

Answer (score 0):

Весьма вероятно, что дело действительно в вирусах. Для очистки советую скачать Dr. Web Curelt - одноразовая утилита, чистит ОЧЕНЬ хорошо!
Не знаю, как в других браузерах, но в Mozilla Firefox можно установить дополнение "AdBlocPlus" (нажмите "Настройки" - там найдёте вкладку "дополнения").